# Mobile processors with hardware support for efficient bounds checking

Tags: mobile, hardware, buffer-overflow, hardening, memory

Are there any mobile or embedded processors that provide hardware support for efficient bounds checking?

Intel's newest x86 processors provide [MPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MPX), which enables compilers to add automatic bounds checking to C/C++ code in a way that's more efficient than can be done through software alone.  Are there any lower-power mobile/embedded processors that offer similar hardware support for bounds checking?

I haven't been able to find any, but I don't know if I'm just looking in the wrong place.

Comment: What range are you targeting? I can't think of any ARM-A feature that matches your description. I suspect that some processors used in smartcards have such features. But in general this sounds like it would have a non-negligible power draw, which would make it unlikely on mobile processors.

Comment: @Gilles, primarily the higher end (say, ARM or Atom or PowerPC or similar) rather than, say, a 8-bit microprocessor... though I'd accept any example at all.

Comment: I'm sure Daniel Micay would know. He's taught me more about ARM architecture security features (low-level PAN/PXN behavior, etc) than I'd ever find out on my own.